# Can't remote into Windows server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell server wired into the router.  I was able to connect to it with my laptop (laptop is wireless) before my router died.  My verizon router went kaput, and I got everything else back up and running on the wireless network other than the remoting in feature, even though I can access the server through windows explorer just fine.

Any ideas why?  What do I need to check?

**UPDATE**: Interesting scenario, Network Discovery is off; I turn it on and save, but for some reason, even after that, network discovery is turning itself off... no idea why that is happening?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would get a better answer over at SuperUser. It will likely get sent over there very soon.

Comment: Really?  What's the fine line between the two sites?  I thought since this was a server issue, this was the appropriate forum?

Comment: "Server Fault is for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity."-FAQ. Your question sounds like the server is your personal hardware, that may not be the case for your question but that is generally the line here. For more detail just read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the resolution, I was missing some services being started: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2networking/thread/17e7b386-53ea-411c-8d90-cf4a6229ba27